# Strange (?) for comprehension evaluation in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, for-comprehension

Now, it took me **a while** to figure out why my recursion is somehow managing to blow the stack. Here it is, the part causing this problem:

```
scala> for {
     |   i <- List(1, 2, 3)
     |   j = { println("why am I evaluated?"); 10 } if false
     | } yield (i, j)
why am I evaluated?
why am I evaluated?
why am I evaluated?
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List()
```

Isn't this, like, insane? Why at all evaluate `j = ...` if it ends in `if false` and so will **never** be used?

What happens when instead of `{ println ... }` you have a recursive call (and recursion guard instead of `if false`), I have learned. :<

Why?!

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you coming from Python and expecting this to be like their inline if expression?

Comment: @nafg, not at all. =) I've never written a line in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you structure your loop like this, it will solve your problem:

```
scala> for {
     |   i <- List(1, 2, 3)
     |   if false
     |   j = { println("why am I evaluated?"); 10 }
     | } yield (i, j)
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List()
```

Scala syntax in a for-loop treats the if statement as a sort of filter; [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_for_loop.htm) has some good examples.

One way to think of it is to walk through the for loop imperatively, and when you reach an if statement, if that statement evaluates to false, you continue to the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say the accepted answer could say more.

This is a parser bug.

Guards can immediately follow a generator, but otherwise a `semi` is required (actual or inferred).

[Here is the syntax.](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L158)

In the following, the line for `res4` should not compile.

```
scala> for (i <- (1 to 5).toList ; j = 2 * i if j > 4) yield j
res4: List[Int] = List(6, 8, 10)

scala> for (i <- (1 to 5).toList ; j = 2 * i ; if j > 4) yield j
res5: List[Int] = List(6, 8, 10)
```

What happens is that the val def of j gets merged with the i generator to make a new generator of pairs `(i,j)`.  Then the guard looks like it just follows the (synthetic) generator.

But the syntax is still wrong.  Syntax is our friend!  It was our BFF long before the type system.

On the line for `res5`, it's pretty obvious that the guard does not guard the val def.

Update:

The implementation bug was downgraded (or upgraded, depending on your perspective) to a [specification bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7937).

Checking for this usage, where a guard looks like a trailing if controlling the valdef that precedes it, like in Perl, falls under the purview of your favorite style checker.

Comment: +1. Should we fill a bug report? Anyway, the accepted answer showed me how to make it work in somewhat elegant way: just reorder expressions inside the `for`.

Comment: @MichałRus I just filed it. Doesn't matter what answer you accept; you'll never get that hour of your life back. But you weren't wrong for being confused.

Answer (score 2):

When I have questions like that I seek to see how the disassembled code looks like (feeding the .class files to JD-GUI for instance).

The beginning of this for-comprehension disassembled code looks like this:

```
((TraversableLike)List..MODULE$.apply(Predef..MODULE$.wrapIntArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })).map(new AbstractFunction1() { public static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

      public final Tuple2<Object, BoxedUnit> apply(int i) { Predef..MODULE$.println("why am I evaluated?"); BoxedUnit j = BoxedUnit.UNIT;

        return new Tuple2(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(i), 
          j);
      }
    }...//continues
```

where we can see that the array of ints in the *i* parameter maps to an `AbstractFunction1()` whose `apply` method first performs the `println` nomatter what and then allocates `Unit` to the parameter `j` finally returning a tuple of two(i,j) to further pipe it into further filter/map operations (omitted). So essentially the `if false` condition doesn't have any effect and essentially is removed by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you, too, for your insight. :)

Comment: The tools in the ecosystem are scalac -Xprint:typer and in the REPL, :javap (the usual javap).