# the filtering in Scala's for loop

Tags: scala

I'm a new beginner to Scala, and I'm now learning the for statements. I read this tutorial http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-six-if-statements-and-loops/

And in this tutorial, there is a example,

```
for (person: Person <- people
    if !person.female;
    name = person.name;
    if name.contains("Ewing"))
  println(name)
```

If compare this for loop to the for loop in Java, is it like

```
for(person: people) {
   if (!person.female) {
     String name = person.name;
     if (name.contains("Ewing"))   
       println(name)
   }
}
```

or like this:

```
for(person: people) {
   String name = person.name;
   if (!person.female && name.contains("Ewing")) {
     println(name)
   }
}
```

Are the operations (in this example, name = person.name;) executed if the first filter condition "if !person.female;" is not satisfied?

Thanks!

Comment: Another source of confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19611402/1296806

Comment: I was going to say, I'm not sure `for (p: Person <- ps)` works as intended, but maybe it will soon. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11395649/1296806 and Odersky http://stackoverflow.com/a/4958797/1296806 ; the issue links to a commit about it, but I wasn't paying attention. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what the scala compiler generates, compile as `scalac -Xprint:typer`. It gives:

```
  people.withFilter(((check$ifrefutable$1: typer.Person) => check$ifrefutable$1: @scala.unchecked match {
  case (person @ (_: Person)) => true
  case _ => false
}))
//filter is acting as your if-clause
.withFilter(((person: Person) => person.<female: error>.unary_!)).map(((person: Person) => {
  val name = person.name;
  scala.Tuple2(person, name)
}))
//Your next if-clause
.withFilter(((x$1) => x$1: @scala.unchecked match {
  case scala.Tuple2((person @ (_: Person)), (name @ _)) => name.contains("Ewing")
}))
//Print each of them
.foreach(((x$2) => x$2: @scala.unchecked match {
        case scala.Tuple2((person @ (_: Person)), (name @ _)) => println(name)
      }))
    }
  }
```

So in short it as acting as your first mentioned case. But as a concept, it is always recommended to think for-comprehensions as a mapping of `map`, `foreach`, `flatmap` etc.

This is because in many cases while dealing with `yield` you will need to manage types and thinking in terms of `foreach` and `filter` (which in java sense is `foreach` and `if`) will not cover all cases. For example, consider below:

```
scala> for(x <- Option(1);
     | u <- scala.util.Left(2)
     | ) yield (x,u)
<console>:9: error: value map is not a member of scala.util.Left[Int,Nothing]
              u <- scala.util.Left(2)
```

Above `for` comprehension uses `flatmap` and `map`. Thinking in terms of Java `for` loops (`foreach` basically`) will not help in finding the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Scala `for` comprehension unfolds into combination of `map`, `flatmap` and `filter`. In your case `if` is actually a filter for all values that appear before it in this "iteration" of the "loop". So if `if` condition is not satisfied the loop will skip this iteration, so your Java `for` loops behave the same way as Scala example.

For example try this in REPL:

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> for (i <- l
     |      if(i%2 == 0))
     |      println(i)
2
4
6

scala>
```

This is equivalent to:

```
l.filter(_%2 == 0).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it out!

```
for{
  x <- 1 to 10
  if x % 3 == 0
  y = println(f"x=$x")
  if x % 2 == 0
} {
  println(x)
}
```

prints:

```
x=3
x=6
x=9
6
```

So this means that the `y=` line is happening before the second `if` filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would not evaluate the follows expressions as it is a common implementation to do so with AND conditions. You can see here
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Boolean
That scala also has this short circuit implementation when using &&